# Elastic Search: Alternative of flattened datatype in Elastic Search 7.1

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have two Elastic Search version one is **7.3** and the second is **7.1**. I am using `flattened` data type for **Elastic Search 7.3** and I also want to use this data type in **Elastic Search 7.1**. So that I can store my data as I stored in **Elastic Search 7.3**.
I researched about `flattened` data type and get to know that it's supported to 7.x but when I tried in 7.1 it gives me the `mapper_parsing_exception` error.
What I tried is as shown below.

- In `Elastic Search 7.3`

  > Index Creation

  ```
  PUT demo-flattened
  ```

  **Response:**

  ```
     {
      "acknowledged": true,
      "shards_acknowledged": true,
      "index": "demo-flattened"
     }
  ```

  > Insert Mapping

  ```
      PUT demo-flattened/_mapping
      {
          "properties": {
              "host": {
                  "type": "flattened"
              }
          }
      }
  ```

  **Response:**

  ```
      {
          "acknowledged": true
      }
  ```
- In `Elastic Search 7.1`

  ```
   PUT demo-flattened
  ```

  **Response:**

  ```
     {
      "acknowledged": true,
      "shards_acknowledged": true,
      "index": "demo-flattened"
     }
  ```

  > Insert Mapping

  ```
      PUT demo-flattened/_mapping
      {
          "properties": {
              "host": {
                  "type": "flattened"
              }
          }
      }
  ```

  **Response:**

  ```
     {
         "error": {
             "root_cause": [
                 {
                     "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                     "reason": "No handler for type [flattened] declared on field [host]"
                 }
             ],
             "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
             "reason": "No handler for type [flattened] declared on field [host]"
         },
         "status": 400
     }
  ```

I want to use the `flattened` data type in **Elastic Search 7.1**. Is there any alternative to use `flattened` data type in the 7.1 version because `flattened` data type is supported from **Elastic Search 7.3**.

> Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First the flattened is available in 7.1 with X-pack (X-pack is paid feature),
so what I think you can use object type with enabled flag as false
This will help you store that field as it is without any indexing.

```
{
        "properties": {
            "host": {
                "type": "object",
                "enabled": false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read about ```object``` type with ```enabled``` mapping attribute and as well as ```flattened``` field type. I don't think so it's relevant because purpose of both ways are different. Despite this , I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your ElasticSearch. If its the OSS version, then it won't work for you.

You can check it by running `GET \` in the Kibana. You would get something like:

```json
{
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
  }
}
```

But for ElasticSearch that does support `flattened` type, you would get something like:

```json
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
   }
}
```

You can find more details on the official Kibana Github page [No handler for type [flattened] declared on field [state] #52324](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/52324#issuecomment-650105753).

Answer (score -1):

Interally, it works like this

> Similarities in the way values are indexed, flattened fields share much of the same mapping and search functionality as keyword fields

Here, You have only one field called `host`. You can replace this with `keyword`.

## What similarities:

**Mapping:**

```
"labels": {
        "type": "flattened"
      }
```

**Data:**

```
"labels": {
    "priority": "urgent",
    "release": ["v1.2.5", "v1.3.0"],
    "timestamp": {
      "created": 1541458026,
      "closed": 1541457010
    }
  }
```

> During indexing, tokens are created for each leaf value in the JSON object. The values are indexed as string keywords, without analysis or special handling for numbers or dates

To query them, you can use `"term": {"labels": "urgent"}` or `"term": {"labels.release": "v1.3.0"}`.

When it is keyword, you can have them as separate fields.

```
{
 "host":{
   "type":"keyword"
 }
}
```

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/flattened.html#supported-operations)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Gibbs and sorry to say that I already referred a document and you can check in the document `flattened` data type is available from 7.3 and I need in 7.1 and my data is too large i.e domain report from virus total so I want alternative of `flattened` data type in 7.1 so that I can store same data as a single object in 7.1 like in 7.3

Comment: Unfortunately not possible unless you overwrite open source code.